# NameError: name "tkinter" is undefined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to learn `tkinter`, but when I try to import it, and make an instance of the `Tk` class, it gives this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
    module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
  File, line 2, in <module>
    tk = tkinter.Tk()
NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined
```

This is the code I am using:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = tkinter.Tk()
```

Comment: `tk = Tk()`....

Comment: `import tkinter as tk`, then `root = tk.Tk()`. Generally it's best to avoid `from tkinter import *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `import *` you need to only reference the methods that were imported like this.

```
root = Tk()
```

However I think it is better to assign an alias to the tk library so you don't accidentally overwrite other methods and it makes it easier to maintain the code when you start importing a lot of libraries.

So do this instead:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
```